# Множество элементов - слушатель для каждого или общий?

Tags: javascript

На странице имеется неопределённое множество элементов. Необходимо обработать нажатие и отжатие по каждому элементу. Как лучше - назначить слушатель каждому элементу или один на документ, который будет отслеживать клики и сверять их по координатам элементов?

Как влияет количество слушателей на производительность? Отразится на ней назначение в цикле анонимной функции, не вынесенной в переменную?

Для уточнения, во втором случае мы выбираем все элементы, записываем их координаты, назначаем слушатель на документ и при клике проходим по записям, ища клик внутри элемента.

Answer (score 6):

Обычно, в таких задачах, используют один обработчик, такой подход называется делегированием ([паттерн делегирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)). Чем больше слушателей есть на странице тем больше тратится памяти. Если у вас более сложный вариант, то рекомендую провести эксперимент и сравнить методы используя средства отладки.

Только вот координаты вам проверять не надо, достаточно будет проверять `event.target`:

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var target = event.target;

    switch (target.className) { // или тут может быть условие
        'button':
            //...
            break;
    }
});
```

Если вы используете **jQuery**, то примером этого является метод [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

**Еще:**

По поводу цикла и анонимной функции: если мы в цикле будем создавать новую функцию (т.е. определять ее прямо там) то память будет тратится еще и на кучу созданных в цикле функций. Если такое и требуется то следует вынести определение функции из цикла (чтобы она была одна) а в цикле лишь ссылаться на нее, передавая ее в параметре при добавлении события.

**Случай, в котором делегирование может быть не столь эффективным:**

Вначале представьте ситуацию удачную для использования делегирования: есть элемент отлавливающий клики, на нем элементы которые нужно отлавливать прямо на нем, без вложенных в друг-друга других элементов - все ок.

Теперь обратная ситуация: много вложенных элементов, в ваши элементы (которые надо отлавливать) добавлены другие элементы, да еще и вложенные в друг-друга. Теперь, если мы кликнем внутри нашего элемента то можем попасть на глубоко лежащего дочернего элемента. Чтобы найти нужный нам родительский нам придется идти по `target.parentNode` в цикле от нашего элемента до основного на котором событие - это может оказаться более накладным.

Comment: делегирование не панацея. для большого количества вложенных элементов оно может оказаться менее эффективным, чем добавление обработчика каждому нужному элементу

Comment: Да в этом случае может и ухудшить ситуацию. Но задача по описанию больше похожа на простую или даже больше на тестовую для собеседования. Думаю в более сложных задачах выверять это надо конкретно под задачу, экспериментальным методом.

Comment: Это больше претензия к формулировке в ответе: _Разумеется лучше создать один слушатель_. Можно читать как - всегда используй, что не совсем верно.

Comment: Ок, я исправил ответ)

Comment: В каком случае может ухудшить ситуацию? Можно пример?

Comment: Добавил в ответ