# Регистрация обработчиков событий в JavaScript при переборе элементов документа

Tags: javascript, события, ecmascript-6, замыкания

Этот вопрос не дубликат, так как он затрагивает не только замыкания, но и иные распространённые ошибки в JS, а также их устранения используя новые возможности спецификации ES 2015.

При переборе элементов не получается правильно зарегистрировать обработчики события `click` перебираемых элементов. События всех перебираемых элементов, регистрируются анонимной функцией, предназначенной для самого последнего элемента.

По задумке.
1 При наведении на `fieldset` сообщения подсвечивается иконка удаления каждого сообщения, при отведении мышки иконка удаления, соответствующего сообщения, снова угасает.
2 При наведении на иконку удаления всплывает подсказка со временем соответствующего сообщения.
3 При клике на иконку соответствующего сообщения удаления всплывает алерт со временем соответствующего сообщения.

Имею.
1 При наведении на любой `fieldset` сообщения подсвечивается иконка удаления последнего сообщения, при отведении мышки иконка удаления, последнего сообщения, снова угасает.
2 Это единственное, что работает правильно.
3 При клике на иконку удаления любого сообщения всплывает алерт со временем последнего сообщения.

Что я делаю не так, что я тут не понимаю и как мне сделать правильно?

```js
window.addEventListener('load',function()
{
 var imgs=document.getElementsByClassName('right')[0].getElementsByClassName('del');
 for(var i=0,l=imgs.length;i<l;i++)
 {
  var img=imgs[i];
  var doc=document.getElementById('mes-'+img.dataset.date+'-'+img.dataset.fid);
  doc.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){img.style.opacity=1;});
  doc.addEventListener('mouseout',function(){img.removeAttribute('style');});
  img.setAttribute('title','Delete '+img.dataset.title+' message');
  img.addEventListener('click',function()
  {
   if(!isNaN(img.dataset.date)&&img.dataset.date>0&&!isNaN(img.dataset.fid)&&img.dataset.fid>0&&img.dataset.title)
   alert('Are you sure you want to delete '+img.dataset.title+' message?');
  });
 }
});
```

```css
*
{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
  border-radius:5px;
  transition:all 0.2s linear;
}
html,body
{
  height:100%;
  min-height:100%;
}
body
{
  background-color:#fff;
  color:#000;
  font:12px/18px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  margin:0 auto;
}
fieldset
{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
legend
{
  font-weight:bold;
}
div.message
{
  min-width:400px;
  width:400px;
  max-height:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
}
div.message div.left, div.message div.right
{
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}
div.message div.right
{
  width:250px;
  text-align:center;
}
div.message div.right hr
{
  border-top:1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top:10px;
}
div.message div.right hr+span
{
  background-color:#fff;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding:0 10px;
  position:relative;
  bottom:10px;
}
div.message div.right fieldset
{
  margin:0 0 10px;
  padding:10px;
  text-align:left;
  position:relative;
}
div.message div.right fieldset.from
{
  margin-right:50px;
  border-color:#6f6;
  background-color:#dfd;
  color:#040;
}
div.message div.right fieldset.to
{
  margin-left:50px;
  border-color:#66f;
  background-color:#ddf;
  color:#004;
}
div.message div.right fieldset img.del
{
  width:16px;
  top:0;
  right:8px;
}
div.message img.del
{
  position:absolute;
  opacity:0.3;
}
div.message img.del:hover
{
  cursor:pointer;
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru-ru" dir="ltr">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <title>Test</title>
 </head>
 <body> 
  <div class="message">
   <div class="left"></div>
   <div class="right">
    <hr/><span>08.10.2016</span>
    <fieldset class="from" id="mes-1475888362-1">
     <legend>Ilya Indigo&nbsp;<span>03:59</span></legend>
     <img class="del" data-date="1475888362" data-fid="1" data-title="03:59" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del"/>
     <p>Тестовое сообщение<br/>новая строка<br/>ещё одна строка<br/>и ещё одна строка.</p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="from" id="mes-1475888608-1">
     <legend>Ilya Indigo&nbsp;<span>04:03</span></legend>
     <img class="del" data-date="1475888608" data-fid="1" data-title="04:03" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del"/>
     <p>Ещё одно.</p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="to" id="mes-1475889423-2">
     <legend>Ilya Indigo 2&nbsp;<span>04:17</span></legend>
     <img class="del" data-date="1475889423" data-fid="2" data-title="04:17" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del"/>
     <p>Отвечаю.</p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="from" id="mes-1475892511-1">
     <legend>Ilya Indigo&nbsp;<span>05:08</span></legend>
     <img class="del" data-date="1475892511" data-fid="1" data-title="05:08" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del"/>
     <p>Ещё одно.</p>
    </fieldset>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Ответ: Самый простой и быстрый способ объявить все переменные через `let` вместо `var`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как работают замыкания в JavaScript](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/414092/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-javascript)

Comment: даже вот этот лучше: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/272864/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5

Comment: @Grundy Я конечно с JS знаком на 3- по пяти бальной шкале, но одного не пойму, зачем вешают обработчик, выполняющий одни и те же действия, на каждый элемент в цикле? Не проще ли повесить всего ОДИН на контейнер этих элементов, а затем проверять на каком элементе событие произошло. Как правильно поступать?

Comment: @pepel_xD, [здесь уже был вопрос такой](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/556802/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9) как пример. И, если не ошибаюсь, еще несколько было. В двух словах: для каждой задачи стоит отдельно смотреть.

Comment: @pepel_xD
Напишите пожалуйста пример JS-кода, в котором моя задача решается методом делегирования, который вы упомянули.

Comment: @IlyaIndigo, по ссылке в предыдущем комментарии есть пример кода

Comment: @Grundy, Вы имеете ввиду этот?
document.documentElement.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var target = event.target;

    switch (target.className) { // или тут может быть условие
        'button':
            //...
            break;
    }
});
Мне не ясно что тут в условии прописывать и про какие "координаты" имеется ввиду.  Координаты курсора мышки?

Comment: @IlyaIndigo, ага, про координаты было написано ввиду того, что их не надо проверять, чтобы определить по какому элементу попали. Достаточно проверить `target`. во-первых, вешать обработчик тебе надо не на документ, а желательно на ближайший контейнер, например, div с классом right. Далее, проверяешь что target - Это картинка - и если условие выполняется - делаешь то, что надо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На первый взгляд может показаться, что здесь классическая проблема с замыканием, и это она действительно и есть.

Но! Решение здесь намного проще: так как в обработчике подразумевается работа с элементом по которому нажали, проблема замыкания решается использованием *this*, вместо переменной img. Так как, в данном случае *this* - будет, как раз тем элементом, по которому кликнули.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('right')[0].getElementsByClassName('del');
  for (var i = 0, l = imgs.length; i < l; i++) {
    var img = imgs[i];
    var doc = document.getElementById('mes-' + img.dataset.date + '-' + img.dataset.fid);
    doc.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
      // здесь проблема остается, так как обработчик вешается на fieldset
      img.style.opacity = 1;
    });
    doc.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
      // здесь проблема остается, так как обработчик вешается на fieldset
      img.removeAttribute('style');
    });
    img.setAttribute('title', 'Delete ' + img.dataset.title + ' message');
    img.addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (!isNaN(this.dataset.date) && this.dataset.date > 0 && !isNaN(this.dataset.fid) && this.dataset.fid > 0 && this.dataset.title)
        alert('Are you sure you want to delete ' + this.dataset.title + ' message?');
    });
  }
});
```

```css
legend {
  font-weight: bold;
}
div.message {
  width: 400px;
}
div.message div.right fieldset {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  border-color: #6f6;
  background-color: #dfd;
  color: #040;
}
div.message div.right fieldset.to {
  background-color: #ddf;
}
div.message div.right fieldset img.del {
  width: 16px;
  top: 0;
  right: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<div class="message">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <hr/><span>08.10.2016</span>
    <fieldset class="from" id="mes-1475888362-1">
      <legend>Ilya Indigo&nbsp;<span>03:59</span>
      </legend>
      <img class="del" data-date="1475888362" data-fid="1" data-title="03:59" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del" />
      <p>Тестовое сообщение
        <br/>новая строка
        <br/>ещё одна строка
        <br/>и ещё одна строка.</p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="from" id="mes-1475888608-1">
      <legend>Ilya Indigo&nbsp;<span>04:03</span>
      </legend>
      <img class="del" data-date="1475888608" data-fid="1" data-title="04:03" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del" />
      <p>Ещё одно.</p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="to" id="mes-1475889423-2">
      <legend>Ilya Indigo 2&nbsp;<span>04:17</span>
      </legend>
      <img class="del" data-date="1475889423" data-fid="2" data-title="04:17" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del" />
      <p>Отвечаю.</p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="from" id="mes-1475892511-1">
      <legend>Ilya Indigo&nbsp;<span>05:08</span>
      </legend>
      <img class="del" data-date="1475892511" data-fid="1" data-title="05:08" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del" />
      <p>Ещё одно.</p>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Причины ошибки:

Переменные объявленные с помощью ключевого слова [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) имеют функциональную область видимости. Это значит, что ни доступны внутри *всей* функции в которой объявлены и внутри объявленных вложенных функций.

Несмотря на то, что объявление переменной находится внутри [*for*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) будет *объявлена* всего одна переменная, значение которой будет меняться.

Так как обработчики выполняются не сразу внутри цикла, а когда наступает определенное событие, они берут значение указанной переменной в момент выполнения, а это, в данном случае, значение присвоенное на последней итерации цикла.

### Возможные решения:

1. **Создание функции, создающей конкретный обработчик:** в данном случае проблема решается за счет создание функции-фабрики, которая будет создавать функцию обработчика на основе параметра. Частным случаем этого подхода является использование [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/IIFE), когда функция-фабрика вызывается сразу при объявлении

   Пример с именованной фабрикой:

   ```js
   function createClickHandler(img) {
     return function() {
       if (!isNaN(img.dataset.date) && img.dataset.date > 0 && !isNaN(img.dataset.fid) && img.dataset.fid > 0 && img.dataset.title)
         alert('Are you sure you want to delete ' + img.dataset.title + ' message?');
     };
   }

   function createMouseoverHandler(img) {
     return function() {
       img.style.opacity = 1;
     };
   }

   function createMouseoutHandler(img) {
     return function() {
       img.removeAttribute('style');
     };
   }

   window.addEventListener('load', function() {
     var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('right')[0].getElementsByClassName('del');
     for (var i = 0, l = imgs.length; i < l; i++) {
       var img = imgs[i];
       var doc = document.getElementById('mes-' + img.dataset.date + '-' + img.dataset.fid);
       doc.addEventListener('mouseover', createMouseoverHandler(img));
       doc.addEventListener('mouseout', createMouseoutHandler(img));
       img.setAttribute('title', 'Delete ' + img.dataset.title + ' message');
       img.addEventListener('click', createClickHandler(img));
     }
   });
   ```

   ```css
   legend {
     font-weight: bold;
   }
   div.message {
     width: 400px;
   }
   div.message div.right fieldset {
     text-align: left;
     position: relative;
     border-color: #6f6;
     background-color: #dfd;
     color: #040;
   }
   div.message div.right fieldset.to {
     background-color: #ddf;
   }
   div.message div.right fieldset img.del {
     width: 16px;
     top: 0;
     right: 8px;
     position: absolute;
     opacity: 0.3;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="message">
     <div class="left"></div>
     <div class="right">
       <hr/><span>08.10.2016</span>
       <fieldset class="from" id="mes-1475888362-1">
         <legend>Ilya Indigo&nbsp;<span>03:59</span>
         </legend>
         <img class="del" data-date="1475888362" data-fid="1" data-title="03:59" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del" />
         <p>Тестовое сообщение
           <br/>новая строка
           <br/>ещё одна строка
           <br/>и ещё одна строка.</p>
       </fieldset>
       <fieldset class="from" id="mes-1475888608-1">
         <legend>Ilya Indigo&nbsp;<span>04:03</span>
         </legend>
         <img class="del" data-date="1475888608" data-fid="1" data-title="04:03" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del" />
         <p>Ещё одно.</p>
       </fieldset>
       <fieldset class="to" id="mes-1475889423-2">
         <legend>Ilya Indigo 2&nbsp;<span>04:17</span>
         </legend>
         <img class="del" data-date="1475889423" data-fid="2" data-title="04:17" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del" />
         <p>Отвечаю.</p>
       </fieldset>
       <fieldset class="from" id="mes-1475892511-1">
         <legend>Ilya Indigo&nbsp;<span>05:08</span>
         </legend>
         <img class="del" data-date="1475892511" data-fid="1" data-title="05:08" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del" />
         <p>Ещё одно.</p>
       </fieldset>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

   Пример с IIFE:

   ```js
   window.addEventListener('load', function() {
     var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('right')[0].getElementsByClassName('del');
     for (var i = 0, l = imgs.length; i < l; i++) {
       var img = imgs[i];
       var doc = document.getElementById('mes-' + img.dataset.date + '-' + img.dataset.fid);
       doc.addEventListener('mouseover', function createMouseoverHandler(imgParam) {
         return function() {
           imgParam.style.opacity = 1;
         };
       }(img));
       doc.addEventListener('mouseout', function createMouseoutHandler(imgParam) {
         return function() {
           imgParam.removeAttribute('style');
         };
       }(img));
       img.setAttribute('title', 'Delete ' + img.dataset.title + ' message');
       img.addEventListener('click', function createClickHandler(imgParam) {
         return function() {
           if (!isNaN(imgParam.dataset.date) && imgParam.dataset.date > 0 && !isNaN(imgParam.dataset.fid) && imgParam.dataset.fid > 0 && imgParam.dataset.title)
             alert('Are you sure you want to delete ' + imgParam.dataset.title + ' message?');
         };
       }(img));
     }
   });
   ```

   ```css
   legend {
     font-weight: bold;
   }
   div.message {
     width: 400px;
   }
   div.message div.right fieldset {
     text-align: left;
     position: relative;
     border-color: #6f6;
     background-color: #dfd;
     color: #040;
   }
   div.message div.right fieldset.to {
     background-color: #ddf;
   }
   div.message div.right fieldset img.del {
     width: 16px;
     top: 0;
     right: 8px;
     position: absolute;
     opacity: 0.3;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="message">
     <div class="left"></div>
     <div class="right">
       <hr/><span>08.10.2016</span>
       <fieldset class="from" id="mes-1475888362-1">
         <legend>Ilya Indigo&nbsp;<span>03:59</span>
         </legend>
         <img class="del" data-date="1475888362" data-fid="1" data-title="03:59" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del" />
         <p>Тестовое сообщение
           <br/>новая строка
           <br/>ещё одна строка
           <br/>и ещё одна строка.</p>
       </fieldset>
       <fieldset class="from" id="mes-1475888608-1">
         <legend>Ilya Indigo&nbsp;<span>04:03</span>
         </legend>
         <img class="del" data-date="1475888608" data-fid="1" data-title="04:03" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del" />
         <p>Ещё одно.</p>
       </fieldset>
       <fieldset class="to" id="mes-1475889423-2">
         <legend>Ilya Indigo 2&nbsp;<span>04:17</span>
         </legend>
         <img class="del" data-date="1475889423" data-fid="2" data-title="04:17" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del" />
         <p>Отвечаю.</p>
       </fieldset>
       <fieldset class="from" id="mes-1475892511-1">
         <legend>Ilya Indigo&nbsp;<span>05:08</span>
         </legend>
         <img class="del" data-date="1475892511" data-fid="1" data-title="05:08" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del" />
         <p>Ещё одно.</p>
       </fieldset>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. **Использование [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)/[const](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).** Использование данных ключевых слов, которые появились в ES2015, позволяет объявлять переменные область видимости которых текущий блок. Это означает, что на каждой итерации цикла будет создаваться *новая* переменная, поэтому во время выполнения обработчика будет использоваться корректное значение

   ```js
   window.addEventListener('load', function() {
     var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('right')[0].getElementsByClassName('del');
     for (var i = 0, l = imgs.length; i < l; i++) {
       let img = imgs[i];
       var doc = document.getElementById('mes-' + img.dataset.date + '-' + img.dataset.fid);
       doc.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
         img.style.opacity = 1;
       });
       doc.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
         img.removeAttribute('style');
       });
       img.setAttribute('title', 'Delete ' + img.dataset.title + ' message');
       img.addEventListener('click', function() {
         if (!isNaN(img.dataset.date) && img.dataset.date > 0 && !isNaN(img.dataset.fid) && img.dataset.fid > 0 && img.dataset.title)
           alert('Are you sure you want to delete ' + img.dataset.title + ' message?');
       });
     }
   });
   ```

   ```css
   legend {
     font-weight: bold;
   }
   div.message {
     width: 400px;
   }
   div.message div.right fieldset {
     text-align: left;
     position: relative;
     border-color: #6f6;
     background-color: #dfd;
     color: #040;
   }
   div.message div.right fieldset.to {
     background-color: #ddf;
   }
   div.message div.right fieldset img.del {
     width: 16px;
     top: 0;
     right: 8px;
     position: absolute;
     opacity: 0.3;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="message">
     <div class="left"></div>
     <div class="right">
       <hr/><span>08.10.2016</span>
       <fieldset class="from" id="mes-1475888362-1">
         <legend>Ilya Indigo&nbsp;<span>03:59</span>
         </legend>
         <img class="del" data-date="1475888362" data-fid="1" data-title="03:59" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del" />
         <p>Тестовое сообщение
           <br/>новая строка
           <br/>ещё одна строка
           <br/>и ещё одна строка.</p>
       </fieldset>
       <fieldset class="from" id="mes-1475888608-1">
         <legend>Ilya Indigo&nbsp;<span>04:03</span>
         </legend>
         <img class="del" data-date="1475888608" data-fid="1" data-title="04:03" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del" />
         <p>Ещё одно.</p>
       </fieldset>
       <fieldset class="to" id="mes-1475889423-2">
         <legend>Ilya Indigo 2&nbsp;<span>04:17</span>
         </legend>
         <img class="del" data-date="1475889423" data-fid="2" data-title="04:17" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del" />
         <p>Отвечаю.</p>
       </fieldset>
       <fieldset class="from" id="mes-1475892511-1">
         <legend>Ilya Indigo&nbsp;<span>05:08</span>
         </legend>
         <img class="del" data-date="1475892511" data-fid="1" data-title="05:08" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del" />
         <p>Ещё одно.</p>
       </fieldset>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```
3. **Использование вместо [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), функции [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).** Так как в данном случае в замыкании будет использован параметр функции, а не переменная, значение в момент выполнения обработчика события будет корректным. Из-за того, что функция [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) возвращает не массив, а коллекцию, использовать у нее функцию [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) нельзя. Но можно преобразовать эту коллекцию в массив, либо использовать [*`call`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

   Пример:

   ```js
   window.addEventListener('load', function() {
     var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('right')[0].getElementsByClassName('del');
     [...imgs].forEach(function(img) {
       var doc = document.getElementById('mes-' + img.dataset.date + '-' + img.dataset.fid);
       doc.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
         img.style.opacity = 1;
       });
       doc.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
         img.removeAttribute('style');
       });
       img.setAttribute('title', 'Delete ' + img.dataset.title + ' message');
       img.addEventListener('click', function() {
         if (!isNaN(img.dataset.date) && img.dataset.date > 0 && !isNaN(img.dataset.fid) && img.dataset.fid > 0 && img.dataset.title)
           alert('Are you sure you want to delete ' + img.dataset.title + ' message?');
       });

     });
   });
   ```

   ```css
   legend {
     font-weight: bold;
   }
   div.message {
     width: 400px;
   }
   div.message div.right fieldset {
     text-align: left;
     position: relative;
     border-color: #6f6;
     background-color: #dfd;
     color: #040;
   }
   div.message div.right fieldset.to {
     background-color: #ddf;
   }
   div.message div.right fieldset img.del {
     width: 16px;
     top: 0;
     right: 8px;
     position: absolute;
     opacity: 0.3;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="message">
     <div class="left"></div>
     <div class="right">
       <hr/><span>08.10.2016</span>
       <fieldset class="from" id="mes-1475888362-1">
         <legend>Ilya Indigo&nbsp;<span>03:59</span>
         </legend>
         <img class="del" data-date="1475888362" data-fid="1" data-title="03:59" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del" />
         <p>Тестовое сообщение
           <br/>новая строка
           <br/>ещё одна строка
           <br/>и ещё одна строка.</p>
       </fieldset>
       <fieldset class="from" id="mes-1475888608-1">
         <legend>Ilya Indigo&nbsp;<span>04:03</span>
         </legend>
         <img class="del" data-date="1475888608" data-fid="1" data-title="04:03" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del" />
         <p>Ещё одно.</p>
       </fieldset>
       <fieldset class="to" id="mes-1475889423-2">
         <legend>Ilya Indigo 2&nbsp;<span>04:17</span>
         </legend>
         <img class="del" data-date="1475889423" data-fid="2" data-title="04:17" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del" />
         <p>Отвечаю.</p>
       </fieldset>
       <fieldset class="from" id="mes-1475892511-1">
         <legend>Ilya Indigo&nbsp;<span>05:08</span>
         </legend>
         <img class="del" data-date="1475892511" data-fid="1" data-title="05:08" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del" />
         <p>Ещё одно.</p>
       </fieldset>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```
4. **Использовать в обработчиках *this*, и искать элементы относительно элемента *this*.** Так как, при добавлении обработчика с помощью [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), внутри обработчика *this* будет указывать на элемент, к которому добавляли обработчик, то при клике на картинку, вместо замыкания можно использовать *this*. В случае, когда обработчик добавляется на `fieldset` можно найти нужную картинку *внутри* `this`, например с помощью [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

   Пример

   ```js
   window.addEventListener('load', function() {
     var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('right')[0].getElementsByClassName('del');
     for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
       var img = imgs[i];
       var doc = document.getElementById('mes-' + img.dataset.date + '-' + img.dataset.fid);
       doc.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
         this.querySelector('img').style.opacity = 1;
       });
       doc.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
         this.querySelector('img').removeAttribute('style');
       });
       img.setAttribute('title', 'Delete ' + img.dataset.title + ' message');
       img.addEventListener('click', function() {
         if (!isNaN(this.dataset.date) && this.dataset.date > 0 && !isNaN(this.dataset.fid) && this.dataset.fid > 0 && this.dataset.title)
           alert('Are you sure you want to delete ' + this.dataset.title + ' message?');
       });

     }
   });
   ```

   ```css
   legend {
     font-weight: bold;
   }
   div.message {
     width: 400px;
   }
   div.message div.right fieldset {
     text-align: left;
     position: relative;
     border-color: #6f6;
     background-color: #dfd;
     color: #040;
   }
   div.message div.right fieldset.to {
     background-color: #ddf;
   }
   div.message div.right fieldset img.del {
     width: 16px;
     top: 0;
     right: 8px;
     position: absolute;
     opacity: 0.3;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="message">
     <div class="right">
       <fieldset class="from" id="mes-1475888362-1">
         <legend>Ilya Indigo&nbsp;<span>03:59</span>
         </legend>
         <img class="del" data-date="1475888362" data-fid="1" data-title="03:59" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del" />
         <p>Тестовое сообщение
           <br/>новая строка
           <br/>ещё одна строка
           <br/>и ещё одна строка.</p>
       </fieldset>
       <fieldset class="from" id="mes-1475888608-1">
         <legend>Ilya Indigo&nbsp;<span>04:03</span>
         </legend>
         <img class="del" data-date="1475888608" data-fid="1" data-title="04:03" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del" />
         <p>Ещё одно.</p>
       </fieldset>
       <fieldset class="to" id="mes-1475889423-2">
         <legend>Ilya Indigo 2&nbsp;<span>04:17</span>
         </legend>
         <img class="del" data-date="1475889423" data-fid="2" data-title="04:17" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del" />
         <p>Отвечаю.</p>
       </fieldset>
       <fieldset class="from" id="mes-1475892511-1">
         <legend>Ilya Indigo&nbsp;<span>05:08</span>
         </legend>
         <img class="del" data-date="1475892511" data-fid="1" data-title="05:08" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del" />
         <p>Ещё одно.</p>
       </fieldset>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```
5. **Делегация событий вместо цикла.** В данном подходе обработчик вешается не на конкретную картинку, а на контейнер, где лежат все картинки. Внутри обработчика уже определяется по какому элементу щелкнули и выполняются нужные функции.

   Пример

   ```js
   window.addEventListener('load', function() {
     var right = document.getElementsByClassName('right')[0];
     right.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
       if (e.target.className === 'del') {
         if (!isNaN(e.target.dataset.date) && e.target.dataset.date > 0 && !isNaN(e.target.dataset.fid) && e.target.dataset.fid > 0 && e.target.dataset.title)
           alert('Are you sure you want to delete ' + e.target.dataset.title + ' message?');
       }
     });
     [...right.querySelectorAll('img')].forEach(img => img.setAttribute('title', 'Delete ' + img.dataset.title + ' message'));
     var fieldSets = right.querySelectorAll('fieldset');
     for (var i = 0; i < fieldSets.length; i++) {
       fieldSets[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
         this.querySelector('img').style.opacity = 1;
       });
       fieldSets[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
         this.querySelector('img').removeAttribute('style');
       });
     }
   });
   ```

   ```css
   legend {
     font-weight: bold;
   }
   div.message {
     width: 400px;
   }
   div.message div.right fieldset {
     text-align: left;
     position: relative;
     border-color: #6f6;
     background-color: #dfd;
     color: #040;
   }
   div.message div.right fieldset.to {
     background-color: #ddf;
   }
   div.message div.right fieldset img.del {
     width: 16px;
     top: 0;
     right: 8px;
     position: absolute;
     opacity: 0.3;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="message">
     <div class="right">
       <fieldset class="from" id="mes-1475888362-1">
         <legend>Ilya Indigo&nbsp;<span>03:59</span>
         </legend>
         <img class="del" data-date="1475888362" data-fid="1" data-title="03:59" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del" />
         <p>Тестовое сообщение
           <br/>новая строка
           <br/>ещё одна строка
           <br/>и ещё одна строка.</p>
       </fieldset>
       <fieldset class="from" id="mes-1475888608-1">
         <legend>Ilya Indigo&nbsp;<span>04:03</span>
         </legend>
         <img class="del" data-date="1475888608" data-fid="1" data-title="04:03" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del" />
         <p>Ещё одно.</p>
       </fieldset>
       <fieldset class="to" id="mes-1475889423-2">
         <legend>Ilya Indigo 2&nbsp;<span>04:17</span>
         </legend>
         <img class="del" data-date="1475889423" data-fid="2" data-title="04:17" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del" />
         <p>Отвечаю.</p>
       </fieldset>
       <fieldset class="from" id="mes-1475892511-1">
         <legend>Ilya Indigo&nbsp;<span>05:08</span>
         </legend>
         <img class="del" data-date="1475892511" data-fid="1" data-title="05:08" src="http://dolinasnov.com/uploads/delete.png" alt="del" />
         <p>Ещё одно.</p>
       </fieldset>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: Спасибо вам за ваш подробнейший ответ, который я ещё до конца не дочитал и не переварил в голове. :-)
Решения одно изящнее другого, мне больше всего понравилась с let.
Что я понял, что практически не знаю JS. Как оказалось, прочитать книгу Флэнигана (5-ое издание) от корки до корки, и научится перебирать элементы DOM-а, обрабатывать события и работать с Ajax-ом Level 2, это ещё совсем не означает, что я я знаю хорошо JS. Про let и forEach я и вовсе не знал. Буду дальше читать и переваривать ваш ответ. :-)
P.S. Надеюсь мой вопрос не удалят, а то очень обидно будет.

Comment: @IlyaIndigo, ну, его точно не удалят, потому что есть заплюсованные ответы, и сам вопрос заплюсован. Максимум может быть закрыт как дубликт, но сейчас я уже не уверен стоит ли.

Answer (score 4):

Ответ находятся тут. https://javascript.ru/basic/closure#primer-oshibochnogo-ispolzovaniya
Причём вступление автора `"С вопроса "Почему это не работает?" люди обычно начинают изучение замыканий."`
Просто, как никогда, попадает в точку и бьёт напролом!

Рабочий пример будет выгладить так.

```
window.addEventListener('load',function()
{
 var imgs=document.getElementsByClassName('right')[0].getElementsByClassName('del');
 for(var i=0,l=imgs.length;i<l;i++)
 {
  var img=imgs[i];
  var doc=document.getElementById('mes-'+img.dataset.date+'-'+img.dataset.fid);
  doc.addEventListener('mouseover',function(x){return function(){x.style.opacity=1;}}(img));
  doc.addEventListener('mouseout',function(x){return function(){x.removeAttribute('style');}}(img));
  img.setAttribute('title','Delete '+img.dataset.title+' message');
  img.addEventListener('click',function(x)
  {
   return function()
   {
    if(!isNaN(x.dataset.date)&&x.dataset.date>0&&!isNaN(x.dataset.fid)&&x.dataset.fid>0&&x.dataset.title)
     alert('Are you sure you want to delete '+x.dataset.title+' message?');
   }
  }(img));
 }
});
```

Но всё же, стандарт ECMA Script 2015 позволяет воспользоваться более простым и изящным методом, объявляя переменные не через `var`, а через `let`.

```
window.addEventListener('load',function()
{
 let imgs=document.getElementsByClassName('right')[0].getElementsByClassName('del');
 for(let i=0,l=imgs.length;i<l;i++)
 {
  let img=imgs[i];
  let doc=document.getElementById('mes-'+img.dataset.date+'-'+img.dataset.fid);
  doc.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){img.style.opacity=1;});
  doc.addEventListener('mouseout',function(){img.removeAttribute('style');});
  img.setAttribute('title','Delete '+img.dataset.title+' message');
  img.addEventListener('click',function()
  {
   if(!isNaN(img.dataset.date)&&img.dataset.date>0&&!isNaN(img.dataset.fid)&&img.dataset.fid>0&&img.dataset.title)
   alert('Are you sure you want to delete '+img.dataset.title+' message?');
  });
 }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

В качестве примера могу привести следующий код:

```
//функция создает объекты в циле, из интерисующих нас параметров box- контейнер в котором находятся DOM эелементы и plate - сами элементы
function createPlates(box, plate, step, speed, bool) {
    var box = document.querySelector(box);
    if(!box) {
        return false;
    } else {
        var plates =  Array.prototype.slice.apply(box.querySelectorAll(plate));
        //в цикле создаем объекты с помощью конструктора (будет описан ниже)
        for(var i = 0; i < plates.length; i++) {
            plates[i] = new ServisePlate (plates[i], step, speed, bool);
        }
        // на контейнер вешаем обработчик на клик
        box.addEventListener('click', function(event) {  
            // И перебираем массив plates с созданными объектами 
            plates.forEach(function(element, i) {  
                // если объект события совпадает со ссылкой на DOM элемент, сохраненной в объекте, запускаем его метод.
                if(event.target == plates[i].elem) {
                plates[i].disclose();  
                // Здесь проверка на клик по дочернему элементу необходимого нам элемента
                }else if(plates[i].elem.contains(event.target)){
                    for(var j = 0; j < plates.length; j++) {
                        if(plates[j].elem.style.height) {
                            plates[j].disclose();
                        }
                    }
                    plates[i].disclose();
                }else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
    createPlates('.servises', '.servises_content', 5, 20, true);
```

Собственно сам конструктор:

```
function ServisePlate(plate, step, speed, headSet) {
        this.elem = plate;
        this.header = plate.querySelector('h3');
        this.body = plate.querySelector('div');
        this.link = plate.querySelector('a');
        if(this.link) {
            this.bodySize = this.body.offsetHeight + this.link.offsetHeight;
        }else{
            this.bodySize = this.body.offsetHeight;
        }
        this.settings = {
            step: step,
            speed: speed
        }
        this.initialSize = this.elem.offsetHeight;
        var self = this;
        function setHead() {
            if(29 < self.header.innerHTML.length) {
            self.header.classList.add('servises_content_header--p18');
            }
            if(59 < self.header.innerHTML.length) {
                self.header.classList.remove('servises_content_header--p18');
                self.header.classList.add('servises_content_header--p1');
            }
        }
        if(headSet === true) {
            setHead();
        }
    }
```

И его метод `disclose`, сохраненный в прототипе:

```
ServisePlate.prototype.disclose = function() {
        function showBody() {
            if(this.elem.offsetHeight < (this.bodySize + this.initialSize)) {
                this.elem.style.height = this.elem.offsetHeight + this.settings.step + 'px';
                setTimeout(showBody.bind(this), this.settings.speed);
            }

        }
        function hideBody() {
            if(this.elem.offsetHeight > this.initialSize) {
                this.elem.style.height = this.elem.offsetHeight - this.settings.step + 'px';
                setTimeout(hideBody.bind(this), this.settings.speed);
            }else {
                this.elem.style.height = '';
            }
        }
        if(this.elem.offsetHeight == this.initialSize || this.elem.offsetHeight >= (this.bodySize + this.initialSize)) {
            if(this.elem.offsetHeight == this.initialSize) {
                showBody.call(this);
            } else {
                hideBody.call(this);
            }
       }
    }
```

Правда некоторые участки кода у меня самого вызывают подозрения на правильность, так как я уже говорил что мой js тянет на 3 с минусом.
Но суть не в правильности тех или иных участков, а в подходе в целом.