# Работа со строковым массивом

Tags: javascript, массивы

Работаю с вводимым пользователем текстом, для начала разбираю строку по пробелу, и далее если слово - ссылка на картинку, вывожу ее, если нет, то оставляю обычным текстом и добавляю в конечное сообщение.
Почему при выполнении функции - аргумента в `checkImage arr[i]` становится **undefined** и получается вместо картинки пустая ссылка. Не могу понять, почему функция не видит элемент массива?

```
var text = document.getElementById("text1").value;
var arr = text.split(" "); // делим строку по пробелу
var mess = new Array(); // новое сообщение

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    if (arr[i].indexOf('.jpg') + 1 || arr[i].indexOf('.png') + 1
            || arr[i].indexOf('.bmp') + 1 || arr[i].indexOf('.gif') + 1
            || arr[i].indexOf('.jpeg') + 1) // если есть какое-либо расширение

    {
        checkImage(arr[i], // проверка ссылки, рабочая - картинка, нерабочая -
                            // текст
        function() {
            var newr = document.createElement("a");
            newr.href = arr[i];
            newr.target = "_blank";
            newr.innerHTML = '<img src= ' + arr[i]
                    + ' style = "max-width:90%">';
            f1.appendChild(newr);
        }, mess.push(" " + arr[i]))

    } else {
        mess.push(" " + arr[i]);
    }
}

var newr = document.createElement("div"); // создать и вывести текст
newr.innerHTML = mess;
f1.appendChild(newr);
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Регистрация обработчиков событий в JavaScript при переборе элементов документа](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/576283/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-javascript-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что замыкания.
Внутри коллбэка

> newr.href = arr[i];

i не то, что вы ожидаете.

В рамках ES6 можно использовать в цикле let, чтобы не страдать от этого регулярно.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: function checkImage(im_url, good, bad) {
     var img = new Image();
 img.src = im_url;
     img.onload = good;
     img.onerror = bad;
 }

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает, но в этом коде почему-то ссылка остается в комментарии, ф-ию проверки выложил комментарием выше, получается. что для рабочей картинки и onload и onerror выполняется

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в функции checkImage вызвать вашу функцию function() передав ей arr[i] в качестве агрумента